# how to sort a csv file by columns and then output the result to a file

Tags: python, csv

column 4 has date of birth (dd/mm/yyyy). I would like this column to be sorted in an increasing order; and then output to a file.

Please assist

Comment: What have you tried? What is the format of the DOB? Please post sample input

Comment: You'll want to read all the date of births into a list, sort the list, and output the list.

Comment: I edited it and now it shows the format of DOB

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
with open('path/to/file') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    rows = [line for line in csv.reader(infile)]
    rows.sort(key=lambda row:datetime.strptime(row[3], "%d/%m/%Y"))
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: thank you but what is lamda in line 5?

Comment: @ap306: That lambda converts the 4th column into machine parseable date/time, for sorting